# How much wire will fit on an industrial reel?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, packing-problem

I am trying to figure out how much cable would fit on an industrial reel.
I have found a few calculators but nothing that will help me calculate this myself.
If you have a reel with dimensions of 3m flange, 1.8m barrel and 1.5m traverse width, and a cable with a diameter of 12cm, how much cable can you spool on to it?

Comment: An _exact_ calculation might be difficult. Are you fine with an approximation? And are the flange and barrels given as radii or diameters?

Comment: Could you please add some description about what is meant by the lengths of flange, barrel and traverse width of an industrial reel?

Comment: I should have been more clear about this, Flange (sidewalls of the reel), Barrel (midsection where the cable is spooled around), traverse width is the width from flange to flange. 
Flange and Barrel are given in diameters.

Comment: Is the 1.8 diameter or radius?  and is the 3m flange the outer diameter, or radial distance?

Comment: Real analysis for a reel. This is more like a geometry problem and the tags should reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a packing problem. The reel has barrel diameter $b = 1.8\,{\rm m}$, **flange height** $f = 0.6\,{\rm m}$ and width $w = 1.5\,{\rm m}$. Each coil has diameter $d = 0.12 \,{\rm m}$

<sub>Note that flange height $f$ is given such that the outside diameter of the reel is 3 m.</sub>

[image: fig1]

Above shown the general geometry with the position of an arbitrary wire indicated axially by $x$ and radially by $r$.

Each coil (circle in the diagram above) has length $\ell = 2 \pi r$ so if develop a relationship for each radius we can find the total length. Each stacked layer has a different radius $r$.

We also need to know how many coils fit along the width. Coils will tend to nestle in a hexagonal shape in layers. Each layer is offset by half a diameter from the previous one and two layers must fit in $w$.

The condition is $  (n + \tfrac{1}{2})\,d \leq w$ with solution $\boxed{n=12}$ coils side by side for each layer.

The total number of stakcs $m$ is whatever is needed to have the outer diameter of the top layer inside the flange diameter (unlike how I drew it above).

$$\begin{array}{r|c}
\text{layer} & r \\
\hline
1 & r_1 = \tfrac{b+d}{2} \\
2 & r_2 = \tfrac{b+d}{2} + d \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
3 & r_{\rm i} = \tfrac{b+d}{2} + 2 d \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
 \vdots & \\
 i & r_{\rm i} = \tfrac{b+d}{2} + (i-1) d \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\end{array}$$

The condition is $r_m + \tfrac{d}{2} \leq \tfrac{b}{2} + f$ with solution $\boxed{m = 5}$. Note that the outside diameter of the coils is ${\rm od} = 2 \left( \tfrac{b+d}{2} + (m-1) \frac{d \sqrt{3}}{2} \right) = 2.75\;{\rm m}$ the outside diameter of the flange is $b + 2 f = 3.0\;{\rm m}$ (per problem description)

The *total* length $L$ is thus:

$$ L = \sum_{i=1}^m 2\pi\,n \left( \tfrac{b+d}{2} + (i-1) d \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) = 2 \pi\, m\, n \left( \frac{b}{2} +d \frac{ (m-1) \sqrt{3} +2 }{4} \right)  $$

$$ L = 2 \pi\, (5)\, (12) \left( \frac{1.8}{2} +0.12 \frac{ (5-1) \sqrt{3} +2 }{4} \right) $$

$$ \boxed{ L = 440.3\;{\rm m} } $$

Comment: I just posted a similar solution, and it appears that one of us is off by a factor of 10.

Comment: @Karl - I am double checking now .. I think you must be doing the same.

Comment: Maybe we just interpreted the given measurements differently. OP gave some clarification in a comment.

Comment: @Karl - This is why I included a diagram. And I check my calculation (which I did in a CAS system) and I stand by them.

Comment: @Karl - what is the number of layers and side-by-side coils in your answer?

Comment: My solution avoids counting the layers. I think we just interpreted the measurements differently. You state that the flange diameter is 7.80m, whereas I took it to be 3m since OP commented "Flange and Barrel are given in diameters".

Comment: @Karl - ok I am chaning my $f$ to be they flange _height_ where $b + 2 f = 3\,{\rm m}$

Comment: @Karl - see edits. We are more in-line now. The calculation was correct, but $f$ was interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer, this was excactly what i was looking for @JohnAlexiou. Also a thank you to you as well Karl, this really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick approximation:

- We approximate every turn of the wire as a torus. The small diameter is the diameter of the wire. The large diameter is given by the position of the wire away from the axis of the reel.
- If the diameter of the wire is $d$ and the traverse width is $w$, on every layer you have $w/d$ tori.
- The length of each of these tori is $2\pi r$, with $r$ being the distance from the axis of the reel. So how much is $r$. In the first layer, $$r_1=r_b+\frac12 d$$Here $r_b$ is the radius of the barrel, or half of it's diameter.
- In the second layer the radius is increased by $d$, in the third layer by an additional $d$ and so on. So $$r_j=r_b+(j-\frac12)d$$
- So all we need to do is to sum up all these lengths. But how far do we need to sum? Until $r_max=r_f$, the radius of the flange.$$r_f=r_b+(j_{max}-\frac12)d$$or $$j_{max}=\frac{r_f-r_b}d+\frac12$$
- Total length of the wire is then $$L=\frac wd\sum_{j=1}^{j_{max}}(r_b+(j-\frac12)d)\\=\frac wd\left[j_{max}(r_b-\frac12d)+\frac12j_{max}(j_{max}+1)d\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Another approximate solution: The volume available to contain wire is $h\times(\pi R_2^2-\pi R_1^2)$, where $h$ is the traverse width and $R_2$ and $R_1$ are the flange and barrel radii, respectively. A cross section of the packed wire will look like a [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing), so ideally the wire occupies $\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}\approx90\%$ of the available volume. (Realistically it will be less; John's answer gives a more conservative analysis.) The cable's volume is $L\times\pi r^2$, where $L$ is the length and $r$ is the cable radius.

So we have $L=\frac\pi{2\sqrt3} h(\pi R_2^2-\pi R_1^2)/(\pi r^2)\approx .9h\frac{R_2^2-R_1^2}{r^2}$.

Plugging in $h=1.5, R_1=0.9, R_2=1.5, r=.06$, we get $L=540$ meters.